# Exporting images with java program using NetBeans

Tags: java, image

I know there are a thousand answers on the message boards to this question, and I have tried them all and none of them have worked for whatever reason.  Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/A_Flute");        
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/C_D_Flute");
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/D_E_Flute");
    ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/E_Flute");       
    ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/F_G_Flute");        
    ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/G_Flute");
    ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/B_Flute");
    ImageIcon icon7 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/C_Flute");
    ImageIcon icon8 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/D_Flute");        
    ImageIcon icon9 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/F_Flute");
```

pretty simple, works perfect while it is on my computer.  Whenever I zip the dist folder move the pictures out of the directory on my computer and run the program, I get back empty JFrame's.  So I then did the project/properties/sources/add folder thing, compiled it and still the same result.  Then I moved the classes folder into the dist folder, tried to change the path and see if that worked, still nothing. It sounds like there is a simple answer to this, but I have clearly missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **absolute path names** in the constructors. Examples of absolute path names are "/home/myusername/folder/foo/bar.png" or "C:\Folder\Graphics\foo\bar.png".
Your code given in your posting always wants to read exactly from the given path at runtime. If you move the graphics to a different folder, you're program won't be able to find them. This way, the graphics aren't included/packed into your program, but they're loaded at runtime (not compile time!) from the path specified in the constructor.

Such absolute paths are very bad practice because they prevent your program from being portable. Other people won't be able to run your program on their computers. Because if you try to run that on a different machine, the code will probably fail, because the path "/home/james/..." might not exist on that computer. Maybe your user doesn't even use Linux or at least his user name is not "james".

So you have to **get rid of the absolute paths**. Instead, you should take care to include your graphics in your project and have them being put into the JAR archive.

One approach would be putting your graphics into your project's directory structure and then doing something like this:

```
URL imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/A_Flute.png");
ImageIcon fluteIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

This, of course, won't work if your graphics stay in your home folder. You have to copy the graphics.

Comment: Trying to get that to work, and now, unfortunately I am running into the can't call a non-static method from a static one.  I have the above code in it's own method, Flute.Flute, but I am trying to call it from the main method.

Comment: Finally figured it all out and the program works great.  Thank you for your help, I probably wouldn't have figured it out on my own.